# Oracle: Get column name based on a value in a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is there a way to get the name of the column based on its value.

**For example**

Let's say i have a table called access which has only one row at all times, but differs from one schema to another. Also the value can only be either be 0 or 1)

```
field0 | field1
---------------
   1    |  0
```

Is there a way to select column 'field0' based on the value = '1'?

I know i can do it using code for a particular table, but i want to do it using a oracle query.

The only idea i had was to check

```
select column_name from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='table' -- but no way to check for value;
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not with standard SQL - you will need dynamic SQL for this, which is generally not a good idea. What is the business problem that leads to this question? Perhaps there are better approaches.

Comment: The goal was to show/hide form fields based on the column names returned from this query. But i want to build a class that handles this for all pages, not have to do this for each page.

Comment: this is a strange setup, but have you tried joining all_tab_columns with your "access" table?  But I agree with mathguy, most likely a better approach

Comment: @user1751510, Your approach is not good. However, you shall achieve your scenario by dynamically build sql and comparing. Please refer my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Your Approach is inappropriate and there are much better ways to handle your scenario, like having a properties like records in ACCESS table instead of referring the column names for business.

However, You can achieve your scenario using below.

```
DECLARE
  columnName varchar(128);
  sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(500);
  input1 VARCHAR(20);
  input2 VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN
  input1 := '1';
  input2 := 'schema_Name';
  FOR r IN (select column_name from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where OWNER = 'DUMMY_TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME='T_PA_CASE' AND DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR2') LOOP
  BEGIN
   sql_stmt := 'select ' || r.column_name  || ' from ' || input2 || '.ACCESS WHERE ' || r.column_name || ' = :1';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt INTO columnName  USING input1;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('First Matched Column is ----'||r.column_name);
   exit;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    CONTINUE;  
  END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

> Output -  First Matched Column name is
>   ----FIELD0

You shall tweak this to a Function and send input for Schema Name and Value to be compared against, to get the output of first matching column name.

Comment: Thanks Srikanth, i will give it a try.